# How should RESTFUL API for tasks look like if I need two GETs?

Tags: rest, restful-url

I want to design a RESTful API for a website scraping service. A user delegates a task to the service. Each task is a website that has to be scaped. User can check tasks' statuses. When a task is done a user can fetch a task result.
The status can be either "Waiting", "In progress" or "Done", when it is done a user can get a data.

What I have now is:

- `POST /tasks` - post a URL to scrape
- `GET /tasks` - returns a list of tasks

I need two more endpoints: one to get a status of a task and one to get scraped data from a website. How should GET look like?

- `GET /tasks/{id}` - return a status? Or return the data?

Or maybe

- `GET /tasks/{id}/status`
- `GET /tasks/{id}/data`

But what would return `/tasks/{id}/` then?

And what if I would also like to present scapped data as html?
Should I use

- `GET /tasks/{id}/data`  or `GET /tasks/{id}/result`

Comment: It's pretty subjective, as long as it makes sense, you're fine.
how about `/tasks/status/{id}` and `/tasks/results/{id}` ?

Comment: Maybe `GET /tasks/{id}` should return different statuses depending on whether the task is finished? E.g. 204 No Content until there's data, then 200 OK with the data? Or do something like this: https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/, respond to the `POST` with 202 Accepted, provide a Location to poll for the status of the job there, and eventually have that return 303 See Other with the Location of the data.

Comment: @FelDev  Why `/tasks/status/{id}` and not `/tasks/{id}/status` which way is better?

Comment: The status is a property of the task, `/tasks/{id}/status` would make more sense if that's the direction you're going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST /tasks - post a URL to scrape
GET /tasks - returns a list of tasks
```

That's good.  Notice that when you POST successfully, cache invalidation kicks in.  Generic clients will know that the previously returned representation(s) of the list of tasks is no longer valid.

```
GET /tasks/{id} - return a status? Or return the data?
```

Why not both?  `/tasks/{id}` identifies a resource; you can use any sort of representation you like for it.  There's no reason that the representation shouldn't include optional elements.

(Herustic: what would the *web page* look like?  Do you really feel like there need to be two different we pages for this one concept?  If not, then it can probably be a single resource in your API.)

> what if I would also like to present scapped data as html?

Same identifier is fine for multiple representations; the client can use the [Accept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header to describe its preferences to the server.

You may want to give some thought to the problem of how the client knows what representations are possible.  On the web, the specification for HTML describes a number of different kinds of links -- browsers can state different preferences when they encounter a script tag or an image tag, for example.  You'll want something similar in your own media types.

There is *nothing* wrong with deciding that these should all be different resources, too.  Either approach can be implemented in a way that is consistent with the REST architectural style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the constraints but GET /tasks/{id} could return both status and data if available.

If you prefer not to (for example, if getting data too often would be a problem from a performance perspective), it seems sensible to have:

```
GET /tasks/{id} @returns status and other plain task fields
```

and then:

```
GET /tasks/{id}/scrappeddata @returns data
```

Why? Because, that way is probably the most consistent with your model (and/or the mental model in the mind of your API users).

The general rules on resource naming given in Rest API tutorial are helpful: https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Comment: but the point is that status is either "in progress" or "done", so when it is done I return data, when it is in progress I cannot return anything. So calling `GET /tasks/{id}` and receiving either "IN PROGRESS" or data seems semanticaly wrong

Comment: Actually, I thought about something like that as query response : {"status":"done","data":"random scrapped data"} or {"status":"in progress", "data":"" }. It would be semantically right from the task point of view.

Answer (score -1):

There are no hard rules when it comes to naming routes for a RESTFUL api.
You can adhere to a convention, know best practices, advice from SO, but at the end of the day, you're the one designing your API, so you know better than anyone else what would fit your particular use case.

Search for "rest api naming best practices" or "how to structure rest api routes" and you'll get plenty of ideas.

The 2 suggestions me and @jonrsharpe made are both valid, it's up to you to define what makes sense for your project.